# illegal hardware instruction in clang

Tags: c++, clang

This is my code snippet (the header file is trivial so not appear here).

```c
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<optional>
#include<malloc.h>

#include "include/common.h"
using std::list;
using std::string;
using std::optional;

optional<list<string>> split(string content, const char *delimiter) {

    char *buf = (char *)malloc(content.length());
    memcpy(buf, content.c_str(), content.length());

    const char *head = strtok(buf, delimiter);
    const char *foll = buf; // follow ptr
    list<string> l; 

    if(head == NULL){
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    while(head != nullptr) {
        DBG("%s", head);
        // DBG("%s", foll);
        // foll = head;
        head = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    
}
int main(){
    string s("123 12312 123213a as dasd as asd");
    split(s, " ");
}
```

and compile it with `clang -o String String.cpp -g -std=c++17 -I../ -lstdc++`
But it will crash when I execute it.

```bash
squ in  squ-virtual-machine in tinyhttpd/src on master [?] 
❯ ./String
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : 123
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : 12312
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : 123213a
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : as
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : dasd
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : as
[x] split(), String.cpp:25 : asd
[1]    192159 illegal hardware instruction  ./String
```

I use lldb to debug it and find this.

```bash
Process 192296 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'String', stop reason = signal SIGILL: illegal instruction operand
    frame #0: 0x0000000000401458 String`split(content=error: summary string parsing error, delimiter=" ") at String.cpp:24:5
   21           return std::nullopt;
   22       }
   23  
-> 24       while(head != nullptr) {
   25           DBG("%s", head);
   26           // DBG("%s", foll);
   27           // foll = head;
(lldb) p head
(const char *) $0 = 0x0000000000000000
(lldb) n
Process 192296 exited with status = 4 (0x00000004)
```

So I don't understand why the NULL compared with nullptr will throw this exception.

Comment: You forgot your C string's NUL terminator. `memcpy()` needs to go for one more byte, `content.length() + 1`.

Comment: You're also leaking memory here, you never clean up your `buf` allocation. Tip: In C++ prefer `new[]` to `malloc()` and `std::vector` to `new[]` when practical.

Comment: I also don't see a `return` at the end of `split()`, usually that's what causes "illegal instructions". Enable compiler warnings, you should've got one here.

Comment: any code that uses strtok is probably wrong - why the heck would you ever use it? the worst designed function in the history of computing.

Comment: I add a return and it now works well. Cuz I want to debug and see how strtok outputs so don't complete all function code and caused this issue. Thx everyone's help!

Comment: @tadman and prefer std::vector or std::make_unique<char[]> over that. But in this case malloc is totally not necessary.  Since input is already a string, use stringviews to return a view on the substrings. In C++ pointer arithmetic like this is hardly ever needed anymore. Live online example here : https://onlinegdb.com/x5Xbd2jf8

Comment: Note returning an optional isn't really necessary since you also have the option to just return an empty vector or list (which bascially tells you there was nothing to split into)

Comment: `std::strtok` is a function that should be deprecated. There are modern replacements for that in the standard C++ library. Learn to use them and forget about `strtok` which lets you do dangerous stuff manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of splitting a string using current C++, without any low level pointer arithemtic and or manual memory allocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// returns vector of string views to avoid copying of string data
// this function can split on multiple delimiters.

auto split_string(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;
    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}

int main()
{
    auto words = split_string("aaa aa abc aaa", " ");

    for (const auto& word : words)
    {
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks significantly better than anything using `strok()`. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid C-style code and use some useful features of C++ standard library to split a string.

A simple and efficient solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <cstddef>


[[ nodiscard ]] std::vector< std::string_view >
split( const std::string_view inputStr, const std::string_view delimiter = " \t" )
{
    std::vector< std::string_view > foundTokens { };

    if ( inputStr.empty( ) ) [[ unlikely ]]
    {
        return foundTokens;
    }

    using std::size_t;

    for ( size_t start { inputStr.find_first_not_of( delimiter ) }, end { }
          ; start != std::string_view::npos; )
    {
        end = inputStr.find_first_of( delimiter, start );
        foundTokens.emplace_back( inputStr.substr( start, end - start ) );
        start = inputStr.find_first_not_of( delimiter, end );
    }

    return foundTokens;
}

int main( )
{
    const std::string text { "123 12312 123213a as dasd as asd" };
    constexpr std::string_view delimiter { " \t" };
    std::vector<std::string_view> tokens { split( text, delimiter ) };

    if ( tokens.empty( ) )
    {
        std::cout << "No tokens were found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Found tokens are the following:\n";
        for ( const auto token : tokens )
        {
            std::cout << token << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The string that you pass to the above function as the first argument should be alive after the function returns because the `string_view`s in the returned `vector` point to the buffer of the `inputStr`. In other words, those returned `string_view`s cannot outlive the original string that was passed to the above function's `inputStr` parameter. Otherwise those returned `string_view`s will point to deleted memory and thus the program will have undefined behavior. In case you really don't want this kind of behavior you can replace all instances of `std::string_view`s with `std::string`s and that will prevent the issue from happening though at the expense of less efficient code.